# Why won't the pipes show up or move?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a flappy bird program for class, but the pipes will either not move or will not appear. Does anyone know the solution to my problem.

```
### SETUP ###
import pygame, random
pygame.init()
c=pygame.time.Clock()
window = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 400])
window.fill((255, 255, 255))
playing=True
drop=1
x=0
points=0
highscore=0
dead=False
height=random.randint(50,280)
t=0
point_counter=1
play_again=False
#start
print("Press any key to start.")
while not play_again:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            play_again=True
### MAIN LOOP ###
while playing:
    play_again=False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
    ### GAME LOOP ###
    while playing and not dead:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                playing = False
            #jump
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                drop=-10
        top_pipe=pygame.Rect(500+t,0,75,height)
        bird=pygame.Rect(200,200+x,75,50)
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        #hitting ground or ceiling
        if bird.y>=350 or bird.y<=0:
            dead=True
        if top_pipe.x==-75:
            top_pipe.x=500
            t=0
            point_counter=1
            height=random.randint(50,280)
        bottom_pipe=pygame.Rect(500-t,height-70,75,1000)
        t-=1
        # if hits pipe
        if top_pipe.x<250 and top_pipe.x>150 and (bird.x<height or bird.x>height+20):
            print("You died!")
            dead=True
        elif top_pipe.x<150 and point_counter==1:
            points+=1
            point_counter=0
        #gravity
        drop+=1
        x+=drop
        #body
        pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,255,0),bird)
        #eye
        pygame.draw.circle(window,(0,0,0),(bird.x+60,bird.y+10),2)
        pygame.display.flip()
        #pipes
        pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,255,0),top_pipe)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,(0,255,0),bottom_pipe)
        #framerate
        c.tick(30)
    x=0
    drop=1
    window.fill((255,255,255))
    bird=pygame.Rect(200,200+x,75,50)
    #body
    pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,255,0),bird)
    #eye
    pygame.draw.circle(window,(0,0,0),(bird.x+60,bird.y+10),2)
    pygame.display.flip()
    if points>highscore:
        print("New highscore!: "+str(points))
        highscore=points
    elif points==highscore:
        print("You matched your highscore!")
    else:
        print("Try again!")
    pygame.time.wait(2000)
    print("\n"*100)
    print("Highscore: "+str(highscore))
    print("Press any key to play again.")
    dead=False
    while playing and not play_again:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                playing=False
            elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                play_again=True
```

I cannot find where the pipes are prevented from moving, if they are.

Comment: Try to make your code as readable as possible if you need to ask for help. Put a space between operators (=, ==, <, >, +, -, /, *, etc) and break the code up into paragraphs once in a while (where you put some of your comments would be a good place). Otherwise, it's like reading an essay without paragraphs, it quickly becomes hard to read and energy-consuming. Rename variables such as `c` to `clock` so they explain what they are so the reader don't have to look up its definition every time. Most importantly, make an [mcve]. Remove everything that's unnecessary but so that the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `pygame.display.flip()` before you draw the pipe rects, so you draw them after the window gets rendered.

There also seems to be a problem with the collision detection, but it's your job to figure that out. Take a look at the [collision detection methods](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) of pygame.Rect.

Comment: Thank you! I know how to do this now.